# Why does ReactJS component disappear after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to show `Instructor Profile` component after user clicked `login` button in `Instructor Login Form`

**It works fine until I refresh the page, that `User Profile` component disappears after the refresh**

Here is the screenshot of the page once a user clicked `login`

[image]

And here is the screenshot once I refresh this above page:

[image]

As you can see in this second screenshot, component has disappeared (which said **Welcome to the profile**

This is how my `InstructorLoginForm` looks like

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import InstructorProfile from "./instructor-profile";
import InstructorLoginFormComponent from "./instructor-login-form-component";

export default class InstructorLoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };

    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangePassword(e) {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleOnClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push(`/instructor/${this.state.username}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            render={props => (
              <InstructorLoginFormComponent
                {...props}
                username={this.state.username}
                onChangeUsername={this.onChangeUsername}
                password={this.state.password}
                onChangePassword={this.onChangePassword}
                handleOnClick={this.handleOnClick}
              />
            )}
          />

          <Route
            path={"/instructor/:username"}
            render={props => (
              <InstructorProfile {...props} username={this.state.username} />
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how my `InstructorLoginFormComponent` looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class InstructorLoginFormComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  handleOnClick(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("Hello");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container h-100" style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
          <div className="user_card bg-dark">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">              
            </div>
            <div
              className="d-flex justify-content-center form_container"
              style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
            >
              <form>
                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                  <div className="input-group-append">
                    <span className="input-group-text bg-info">
                      <i className="fa fa-user" />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    value={this.props.username}
                    onChange={this.props.onChangeUsername}
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    className="form-control input_user"
                    placeholder="username"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="input-group mb-2">
                  <div className="input-group-append">
                    <span className="input-group-text bg-info">
                      <i className="fa fa-lock" />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    value={this.props.password}
                    onChange={this.props.onChangePassword}
                    type="password"
                    name="passwordbutton"
                    className="form-control input_user"
                    placeholder="password"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      className="custom-control-input"
                      id="customControlInline"
                    />
                    <label
                      className="custom-control-label"
                      htmlFor="customControlInline"
                      style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
                    >
                      Remember me
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>

            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
              <Link
                to={`/instructor/${this.props.username}`}                
                type="button"
                className="btn login_btn bg-info">
                Login
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my `InstructorProfile` looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class InstructorProfile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>          
        <h1>Welcome to the profile {this.props.username}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone please give me a solution for this? And I need to get rid of that Navigation bar above, which shows everytime, doesn't matter which component loads. How can I do that too?

> PS: to this point I haven't configured any database, 'cause I need to check if components work as intended before making any calls to database

Comment: How are your persisting your login credentials? Refreshing the page will clear your state.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you put it in codesandbox and give the link here. So, other people can test and recommend you solution. One of the problem I see is your component structure is not scalable. for e.g username and password should be part of login component and Routing should be in a different component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
      <Route path="/instructor/:username" component={InstructorProfile} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```

Doing this you are putting the routes at parent level now each component has it's own purpose and state. From the LoginForm you should handle the username, password login etc. Once successful you can redirect the user to ("/instructor/username"). And when the redirect happens with username on url you can access that in **Profile** component by `this.props.match.params.url`. This solves both of your problems. Now for the navigation bar you can put that inside Instructor component or create a InstructorRouter component and put the Navigation bar there and more routing logic. This way you are limiting the navigation bar inside instructor profiles only. Now for the case of username being lost after refresh. If you have the username on url you will retain it even after page refresh. But the good idea is to keep that in localStorage if you need it often. But if your url isn't going to change or doesn't matter much you can just go with it.

Comment: I am new to React and most of the things you said here isn't clear sir. Can you provide me with examples?

Comment: Just the basics first in react each component should have a purpose. For eg. username and password are part of login so it should be inside login. You need to study about components more it will give you more idea. About the router thing I think the best example is https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start Here you can see how the multiple routing is managed. Try to copy this code and test it yourself locally you will understand a lot.

Comment: My username and password both are in the `InstructorLoginFormComponent` component. And then I render that component to the `InstructorLoginForm` component

Comment: You have two components InstructorLoginForm and InstructorLoginFormComponent. It doesn't make sense. You should just have one. The instructorLoginFormComponent and username, password should be there. The InstructorLoginForm should be named something different and it should have the Routes only.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `InstructorLoginForm` does not render at all when you load `localhost:3000/instructor/admin`. Check that your app runs correctly when accessed from different urls. Add some logging to `InstructorLoginForm`:

```
  render() {
    console.log('hello, I am InstructorLoginForm');
    return (
      <Router>
      .....
```

`this.state.username` gets empty after you refresh the page. You should use this code instead:

```
     <Route
        path={"/instructor/:username"}
        render={props => (
          <InstructorProfile {...props} username={props.match.params.username} />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: Even after using this code, it doesn't work. Still the same.

Comment: This code fixes another issue. I've updated my answer to help you with debugging. Please provide the code which renders your app and `InstructorLoginForm`.